# Распарсить двумерный массив используя php

Tags: массивы, php, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется следующий массив:

```
$udata = array(
  array('ID' => '1','userID' => '0'),
  array('ID' => '2','userID' => '0'),
  ...
);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы php скрипт вывел следующее:

```
id = 1, userID = 0;
id = 2, userID = 0;
...
```

Comment: foreach ($names as $value) {

echo "<b>$value</b><br>";

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простое решение:

```
foreach ($udata as $v) {
  echo 'id = ' . $v['ID'] . ', userID = ' . $v['userID'] . ";\n";  
}
```

Этот код выведет текст с данными о каждом пользователе в отдельной строке, однако браузер склеит их в одну строку. Решается либо оберткой в тег PRE либо заменой \n на тег BR.

Comment: белый экран вместо выполнения скрипта

Comment: @Лёва Черненко, проверил еще раз - данные выводятся. Проверьте, все ли нормально с массивом на входе.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($udata as $key) {
echo "$key";
}
```